# Do avcodec_receive_frame and avcodec_send_packet block / how to design ffmpeg decoding loop?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, decoding

I'm thinking about how to design a loop that reads frames from internet, feed to ffmpeg decoder and then receive from ffmpeg to send to a render.

Take this pseudocode loop in consideration:

```
while true {
    auto packet = receive_packet_from_network();
    avcodec_send_packet(packet);
    auto frame = alloc_empty_frame();
    int r = avcodec_receive_frame(&frame);
    if (r==0) {
        send_to_render(frame);
    }
}
```

do `avcodec_send_packet` or `avcodec_receive_frame` block or ffmpeg has an internal thread? I'm concerned about this loop because it waits for packets from network, so it has some delay. I'd like to do something like this instead:

```
//thread 1
while true {
    auto packet = receive_packet_from_network();
    avcodec_send_packet(packet);
}
//thread 2
while true {
    auto frame = alloc_empty_frame();
    int r = avcodec_receive_frame(&frame);
    if (r==0) {
        send_to_render(frame);
    }
}
```

however, now, if `avcodec_receive_frame` does not block, then this loop would run too fast, millions of times per second.

So, how should I design the send/receive of packets in ffmpeg in the most efficient way? I don't want to spend cpu cycles like in the thread2 loop.

Comment: You should read the documentation. The methods do not block. And will return EAGAIN, when there is no work to be done.

Comment: @szatmary isn't there a way to poll for available frames?

Comment: Yes. Call receive_frame. If there is a frame, you will git it. If not it will return EAGAIN. it’s all in the docs.

Comment: @szatmary I meant a smart poll. For example, it blocks and returns when there is an available frame

Comment: Thats not what polling is, that's a blocking interface. A blocking interface is not needed (and not recommended). Once  `avcodec_receive_frame` returns EAGAIN, It will continue to return EAGAIN until `avcodec_send_packet ` is called. If you want to simulate a blocking interface, you can simulate it with a mutex.

Comment: @szatmary ok right. I was talking about an efficient polling though, but it looks like it's impossible

Comment: There is no such thing as efficient polling. Polling is what you do when you have no other choice.

Comment: @szatmary if ffmpeg wanted to it could implement, with a condition variable, what I call "efficient polling". You could call `wait_decode(35)` for example to wait for decode or return in 35 milliseconds. No CPU time wasted.

Answer (score 0):

event driven, like this:

```
while true {
auto packet = receive_packet_from_network();
std::async(std::launch::async, [packet]() {
    avcodec_send_packet(packet);
    auto frame = alloc_empty_frame();
    do{
       int r = avcodec_receive_frame(&frame);
       if (r == 0) {
        send_to_render(frame);
      }
    }while(r == 0)
   
});}
```

Comment: Wont this make `avcodec_receive_frame` be called once every after a packet is received? I need to call more than that

Comment: you can call more in loop

Comment: Question: were You able to implement 2 threads as You planned? I mean this idea with feed thread with avcodec_send_packet() and render thread with avcodec_receive_frame(). I am going to use similar scheme but still it does not work for me. I read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73859236/ffmpeg-concurrent-video-decoding that this is simply not possible because "impossible. ffmpeg already does all it possibly can. you should never call those functions on the same context from multiple threads"