# FFMPEG Concurrent Video Decoding

Tags: c, ffmpeg, concurrency, parallel-processing

So, right now my program is decoding an input video sequentially and doing math on each frame to determine black frames. I feel like decoding the video frames concurrently could greatly improve the speed of my program, but I'm not really sure if FFMPEG supports that. Currently I generate 2 threads that call avcodec_receive_frame and avcodec_send_packet, but It doesn't seem to be working like the sequential implementation. Does anyone know the proper way to decode in parallel?

Comment: impossible. ffmpeg already does all it possibly can. you should never call those functions on the same context from multiple threads.

Comment: Is it really truth that avcodec_send_packet() and avcodec_receive_frame() cannot be called on same context from different threads? Yes, I am trying to make this but it fails with segfault randomly.. Very puty. Usually cycle is 1) read data from network 2) avcodec_send_packet() 3) avcodec_receive_frame() 4) render frame. It is clear that during render I loose time not feeding decoder with another data. It will be time gap with empty input buffer during I render. Only 2 separate threads: feed and render theoretically can provide pipeline especially with HW decoder. But I cannot make it work yet.